# unwanted Purple colour in my render

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, hdri

so , i started making a short film of a robot mystery , and had made a few renders , it was all okay , until[image] i made my 5th render , the whole lighting system glitched and the lights started pitching to purple , first i thought , that my hdri might have caused the problem but the hdri is attached but still , this is the problem
PS , im a noob

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you changed where that HDRI file was, reloading it may solve the problem, either that or you disconected a node somewhere.

Comment: ok il try and then folow up

Comment: yeah thank you it really go changed my nodes were messed up , tq